# Planetary motion integral

Tags: tensors, general-relativity

I was reading Planetary Motion (page 117) in Barry Spain's *Tensor calculus*, and stupidly enough, I didn't understand this. The equations are:

$$\frac{d^2\psi}{d\sigma^2} + \frac{2}{r}\frac{dr}{d\sigma}\frac{d\psi}{d\sigma} = 0,$$

$$\frac{d^2t}{d\sigma^2} + \frac{2m}{c^2r}\left(1-\frac{2m}{c^2r}\right)^{-1}\frac{dr}{d\sigma}\frac{dt}{d\sigma} = 0,$$

And the next statement reads

> we integrate the above to get
>
> $$r^2\frac{d\psi}{d\sigma} = h, \quad \left(1-\frac{2m}{c^2r}\right) \frac{dt}{d\sigma}= k$$
>
> respectively, for constants $k$ and $h$.

I believe it is a simple question, as no steps are given, but I am unable to get it. I tried everything I could, substitutions et al, but to no avail. So please entertain this silly question. Thank you very much...

### EDIT

Please show the integration, I dont want to confirm the validity of the answers by working backwards, but I want to establish them.

EDIT (2)

I want to see the actual integration. If I am right, then the second term($2r\frac{dr}{d\sigma}\frac{d\psi}{d\sigma}$) of the first equation yields the desired result which is $r^2\frac{d\psi}{d\sigma}$ when integrated wrt $d\sigma$. It means that the integral of $r^2\frac{d^2\psi}{d\sigma^2}$ is $0$...I think the integral simplifies to $\frac{d}{d\sigma}\int{r^2d\psi}$, and to get the required answer, it should be zero or a constant.....But HOW??? PLease help....

Comment: Differentiate the two latter expressions with $h$ and $k$ treated as constants then you will see.

Comment: You will never get anything from your $2^{nd}$ equation, there is a typo in Eq 69.3 in the book (compare it with Eq. 69.1). The $2^{nd}$ equation should be $$\frac{d^2t}{d\sigma^2} + \frac{2m}{c^2\color{red}{r^2}}\left(1-\frac{2m}{c^2r}\right)^{-1} \frac{dr}{d\sigma} \frac{dt}{d\sigma} = 0$$ instead.

Comment: @Rene Schipperus, I dont want to CHECK the soultion by differentiating, I want to GET it..i.e. I want to know how you integrate the equations...Can you please help me with it??(check my edit)

Comment: Sorry but I think they integrated them by noticing that they are the derivatives of products.

Comment: But @Rene Schipperus, there has to be a mathematical description of the integral, right???Its more like we have to "prove" the result, so we cant give an account of your observation, and are asked to show the whole working... It is understood that the fact it is the expansion using Leibnitz rule, but there should be a well defined integral for it, right..(And please see if my NEW edit is right or wrong??)

Comment: ALLRIGHT, I got it.......You don't need to work back or use the chain rule explicitly..